# Horizontal alignment of a tabularx environment inside a figure

Tags: floats, horizontal-alignment, tabularx, ltablex

I'm making some figures that must have with a little description in a `tabularx` environment. I'd like to align the `tabularx` to the left margin, however it continues appearing in the center.

I'm using the `ltablex` package for other tasks in the document (e.g. `\keepXColumns`), but this package appears to be the responsible for my frustration. How can I align a `tabularx` environment to the left in this conditions and using these packages? There another alternative packages?

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx,graphics}
\usepackage{ltablex}%<---This package

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}\par
\footnotesize
\raggedright
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{>{\bfseries}rX}
Description 1:&Some text\\
Description 2:&Some text\\
\end{tabularx}
\caption{This is a figure example}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}\par
\footnotesize
\begin{flushleft}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{>{\bfseries}rX}
Description 3:&Some text\\
Description 4:&Some text\\
\end{tabularx}
\end{flushleft}
\caption{This is a figure example}
\end{figure}


\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{>{\bfseries}rX}
Description 5:&Some text\\
Description 6:&Some text\\
\end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Off-topic: Don't load both `graphicx` and `graphics`; the former should suffice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you were on right track :-) how you use `\keepXColumns`? it works fine for me:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx,graphics}
\usepackage{ltablex}%<---This package
\keepXColumns % <--- added

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}\par

\footnotesize
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{>{\bfseries}rX}
Description 1:&Some text\\
Description 2:&Some text\\
\end{tabularx}
\caption{This is a figure example}
\end{figure}

\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{>{\bfseries}rX}
Description 5:&Some text\\
Description 6:&Some text\\
\end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```

[image]